# Show Results In Iframe instead of div

Tags: javascript, iframe

So, I get the results that I need with the function, but I need to create an iframe or display the results.  What do I need to change to do this?  I'm assuming it has something to do with the scopedetails div, but I'm not 100% about that.

```
            function getscope(id){
            var id = id

            var txt = 'Click generate to generate the scope of work now';

            $.prompt(txt,{ 
                buttons:{Confirm:true, Cancel:false},
                submit: function(v,m,f){
                    var flag = true;
                    if (v) { }
                    return flag;
                },
                callback: function(v,m,f){

                    if(v){      
                        $.post('getscope',{sid:id},
                               function(data){
                               $("div#scopedetails").html(data);                                   
                               }
                        );
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Why does it need to be an iFrame?

Comment: The css is fixed and causing spacing errors.  The only thing I can think of is an iframe.  Is there something else that could be used instead?

Comment: You could just strip any inline CSS from the data returned...

Comment: The problem is there is a pagnation div below the altered fiv that is autoset by the template somehow as an absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just set the .innerHTML property on an iframe.  First, you'll need to make sure that the iframe is loaded to a dummy blank page that is part of your domain, you used to be able to use 'about:blank' but no more, security restrictions.  Then you need to get a hold of the iframe's /document/body element and manipulat its DOM.  Much easier to work with a .